# AWS-LAMP Bitnami | External API Call Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, lamp, http2, bitnami

I have Bitnami LAMP Instance running in AWS LightSail. My PHP code is hitting 2 external API (API-1 & API2) for Stock data with two different systems/endpoint.

When i run this code on local, both API-1 & API2 gives successful response. Even if hit both APIs from local browser, both are successful.

But when i run same code in AWS LightSail instance, API-1 is successful but API-2 fails and gives error

> Error: HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: INTERNAL_ERROR (err 2)

i am not sure as what is the potential root cause, both APIs are publicly accessible.

I have done latest updated for APACHE, PHP.

I tried calling both API from local browser: Success,
Tried calling both APIs from Local Desktop with LAMP Stack running: Success

the APIs don't need any API key and are publicly accessible.
AWS Light sail does not have any outbound rule as per documentation so i am little clueless as what can be the issue and what i need to check/fix.